# Update A Single cell within a row in datatable which contains multiple rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

How would i go about updating a single cell in a row so for example Row[0] i want to update the column "Value" with its current value +1. This is code i have which selects the single row but the Value updates with all the column "Value" data then +1

```
public void MetricChange()
    {
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["MetricTable"];
        int value = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(r1 => r1.Field<int>("Value"));
        if (Access.Checked)
        {
            ds.Tables["MetricTable"].Rows[0]["Value"] = value +1;
            //ds.Tables["MetricTable"].Rows[1]["Value"] = value - 1;
            Chart2.DataSource = ds.Tables["MetricTable"];
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

How would i just update the "Value" column within a single row???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it :P

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables["MetricTable"].Rows[0]["Value"]) + 1;
```

Then Update the row by this `ds.Tables["MetricTable"].Rows[0][1] = val`

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are modifying only a single row, you need to do that for each row in the data table.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["MetricTable"].Rows.Count;i++)
    ds.Tables["MetricTable"].Rows[i]["Value"] = value +1;
```

Its always better to check the dataset against null and table existence. Something like.

```
if(ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables["MetricTable"] != null)
```